# What is the best visa option for visiting UK for a week or two from US?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, us-residents, standard-visitor-visas

I was looking through the options of visiting UK for a week or two. With the information available online it is a bit daunting to figure out which is the right visa. I am in US for my studies on an F-1 visa from India.

What is the best option of visiting UK for a week or two from US?

What are the financial documents I should show?

Should the amount be in US dollars or should I convert back to my native currency?

Comment: Please add your citizenship, as responses will need that info.

Comment: @Dorothy I have added Indian

Comment: What is the purpose of your visit?

Comment: You may want to check if you are eligible to apply from the US to the UK - as you are not a permanent resident of the US. It may be that you need to apply for the visa from India.

Answer (score 7):

You need a Standard Visitor visa (you can check this [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa)) and the documents required are listed at [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide). There is no need to exchange currencies.

As far as what financial documents to include as evidence, you can read the [Supporting Documents Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) and [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)